# The least upper bound for $\frac{\sum_{i=0}^m{\binom{m}{i}x^i}}{\sum_{i=0}^{m}{x^i}}$

Tags: combinatorics, optimization, binomial-theorem, geometric-progressions

I have proposed a classifier whose complexity can be written as

\begin{align*}
\mathcal{O}\left(f(m)\right)&=\mathcal{O}\left(\log\left(\max_{x\in(0,1)}\left\{g(x,m)\right\}\right)\right)\\
g(x,m)&=\frac{(1+x)^m(1-x)}{1-x^{m+1}}
\end{align*}

where $m\in\{0,1,2,3,...\},x\in(0,1)$.

There exist an evident upper bound for $g(x,m)$ but it is quite large:

\begin{align}
(1+x)^m=\sum_{i=0}^m{\binom{m}{i}x^i}&<\binom{m}{{\lceil}\frac{m}{2}{\rceil}}\sum_{i=0}^{m}{}x^i\\
&<\binom{m}{{\lceil}\frac{m}{2}{\rceil}}\frac{1-x^{m+1}}{1-x}
\end{align}
\begin{equation}
\longrightarrow \forall x: \frac{(1+x)^m(1-x)}{1-x^{m+1}}<\binom{m}{{\lceil}\frac{m}{2}{\rceil}}
\end{equation}
As you see $\binom{m}{{\lceil}\frac{m}{2}{\rceil}}$ is a generous upper bound.

Translating my question to Combinatorics language, I am seeking for a technique that provides the smallest or a small enough $U_m$ in the below formula.
\begin{equation}
\sum_{i=0}^m{\binom{m}{i}x^i}<U_m\sum_{i=0}^{m}{}x^i
\end{equation}
Can anyone provide any hint, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint. Note that the function 
$$f(x)=\frac{(1+x)^m(1-x)}{1-x^{m+1}}$$ 
is increasing in $(0,1)$ and 
$$\lim_{x\to 1^-} f(x)=\frac{2^m}{m+1}.$$

Comment: Thanks Robert!!